# How to solve advection-diffusion equation by using transformation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The advection-diffusion equation is the partial differential equation
$R\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = D\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial x^2}−\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}$ with initial and boundary conditions 
$C(x,0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\partial C}{\partial x}(x,t)=0$, $C(0,t)=a$ (constant).
I am able to solve this in different ways and getting the same result but when I use the transformation $y=x-t/R$ and $t=t$ this converts my equation into diffusion equation by applying Laplace transform on this I am not getting the same solution after back transformation. I am confused how to change my boundary condition. any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: I do not know how to write in MathJax format but I will try my best is there anyone who can answer my question in this format.

Comment: I'm also working on this... I want to transform ADE into ODE, can you help to figure it?